# In a world where flying cars exist, what kind of features would the cars need to have?

Tags: near-future, flying-machines

Designing a sort of cyper-punkish, futuristic megacity where flying cars have been adopted as opposed to land-based cars to create more space on land and to reduce traffic issues.

It can be assumed that these flying cars work in similar ways to land-based cars (except they fly), so **what kind of safety features would a flying car/vehicle like this need to have to be safe and functional in that kind of situation?**

One idea I had is having a T shaped rear light that is constantly on, and spans the whole width of the vehicle, and down to the bottom, meaning people can see your orientation, how wide the vehicle is and an approximation of the 'danger-zone' around the vehicle.

(I'm not actually able to delete this question, however thank you to those who gave me a few ideas regardless. Due to the massive volume of variables that are involved, I don't think it can really be edited to fit the guidelines.)

Comment: You should add some more info. These flying cars fly like planes, or follow roads like normal cars, only hovering? Are they allowed to fly following any path, or are there airways and airstreets in the cities? Which is their maximum speed? Height ceiling? Depending on those characteristics the safety measures are wildly different.

Comment: Are they piloted manually?

Comment: You might look into [ultralight aviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultralight_aviation), particularly as it related to the US, where [qualifying vehicles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultralight_aircraft_(United_States)) can be operated without any special training or licensing. That said, there are a lot of restrictions on weight, speed, fuel, and location (no ultralights over cities, for instance). But it will give you a starting point.

Comment: They would need to have exactly the features required by the plot. For example, in David Weber [*Honorverse*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honorverse) they have aircars, at least in the People's Republic of Heaven/Republic of Heaven. Those aircars can be flown manually if the user really wants to, because that's kind of important to the plot (twice, once for a dubious suicide and once for a genuine but extremely ill timed accident.)

Comment: It is inappropriate, [SE is not a discussion forum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/are-stack-exchange-sites-forums/92110#92110).  SE's Q&A model is one-specific-question/one-best-answer.  Additionally, this appears to suffer for a lack of research.  Why does combining the functionality of planes and cars not solve your problem?  Externally observable orientation was solved nearly 100 years ago.

Comment: Flying cars are [kinda real already](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helicopter) - why don't you just use safety features they actually have?

Comment: I think a flux capacitor would be nice.

Comment: @JBH It doesn't look like you read my question really, that was just an example of one of the features that could be involved. Thanks for telling me it is not appropriate though.

Comment: I read your question quite thoroughly.  My point is, solutions already exist for what you're asking about.  Stack Exchange is not a discussion forum, so asking aesthetic questions of the type, "what cool/distinctive/aesthetic/different ways can I do this?" are inappropriate.  On the other hand, demonstrating that you've done your reasearch and asking a quesiton like, "Here are the functions I've found and how they're dealt with today, but here's a function not included, how might I deal with that?"  is very much what we're about.

Answer (score 3):

Barring 100% autopilot, a proper safety feature would be a system that:

- Detects and prevents collisions. System has sensors on the vehicle, and it broadcasts position, speed, and direction to other cars, so they can coordinate.
- Avoids designated areas. Not just White house, but 500 feet above residential areas.
- Keeps doors and windows closed while flying, ensures that windows are intact.
- Detects any technical issues. If any sign of trouble is found, system prevents takeoff, or safely lands the vehicle on autopilot.
- Communicates with police/traffic control to confirm that system is operational, and vehicle is safe to fly. Any vehicle without that signal gets scooped up, by a giant butterfly net (if you just shoot it down, it will fall on innocent people).

**The risks** you have to guard against are:
 - Drunk, distracted or inexperienced pilots
 - Breakdown in mid-trip
 - Pranks, littering and invasion of privacy
 - Deliberate terrorism or crime

With land cars, you can prevent it with gates, barriers, and roads. Also the speeds are slower, so driver both driver and potential victims have time to react. Finally, if a car is close enough to hurt you, you can see its license plate.

Flying cars can move in 3 dimensions, so barriers do not work. You will not have time to see and react to a vehicle that is in a free-fall, or out of control. You will not see the any details of a car that dropped a soda bottle on the head of your child.

Current small planes do pose all of these dangers, but they have high cost and licensing requirements that keep irresponsible people from using them. There are also relatively few of them, so you can easily find any mis-behaving pilots.

Comment: Something like a combination of ADS-B In/Out and TCAS connected to the autopilot and having the ability to override the pilot's commands, you mean? (In our world, TCAS, or Traffic Collision Avoidance System, will give Resolution Advisories but leave the ultimate decision to the pilot, on the assumption that (a) the pilot knows what they are doing, and (b) the pilots want to survive.)

Comment: Regarding speed, I've actually flown an airplane just recently at a ground speed of maybe 10-20 km/h. The trick? Ground speed is not air speed, and for airplanes, what matters is air speed, not ground speed. Reasonably low air speed directly into a headwind will do that.

Comment: @α CVn♦ and what was your ground speed when you turned around, and got a tailwind?

Comment: Somewhere around 100-110 km/h, IIRC.

Answer (score 2):

Heavily cushioned base with a low centre of gravity; seats with heavy hydraulic dampening; seatbelts; multiple small reinforced windows instead of a large windscreen; height limiters built in; default forced landing in case of emergency, with regularly spaced emergency landing areas; very loud, very annoying fuel, battery, etc., warnings, that won't allow takeoff at less than 30% optimum levels.

Answer (score 1):

The trouble with questions of this type is that the answers are open ended lists which isn't appropriate to the format. However there's one critical aspect that makes most of the others redundant.

- Permanent autopilot with no possibility of manual control

and I'm afraid you're not getting your personal flying vehicle until that's how they operate.

Comment: when outside the city or on a closed track manual flying should be possible.

Comment: @ratchetfreak, why? 90% of users are borderline dangerous with a ground based vehicle

Comment: @Separatrix 90% is very optimistic ;)

Comment: because there will be people that wanna race or do stunts

Comment: @ratchetfreak ... and that is precisely why you're never going to be allowed to.